# After merging local master branch with the remote one, should you push it back to the remote?

Tags: git, github

I'm a newbie at git so I'm sorry if this question doesn't make sense, but it is scratching my head.
I'm going to try to explain the scenario:

**Point A:** User 1 and User 2 have synced up master branches with the remote repo.

**Point B:** User 1 creates a local branch "U1", where he'll be working. He finishes his tasks first.

**Point C:** User 2 creates a local branch "U2", where she'll be working. It's gonna take a little while to complete her tasks.

**Point D:** User 1 will checkout his local master branch, merge it with U1 and then push it to the remote repo.

**Point E:** User 2 finishes her tasks, and then try to do pretty much the same as User 1 did. Checkout her local master branch, merge it with U2 and then try to push to the remote repo. That's where the problem happens. She doesn't have the latest version of the master branch anymore.

Now, I know User 2 will have to `git pull origin master` before sending her modifications to the remote repo, which will imply a merge with her local master branch and the remote master branch. And, later on, should she push this "new" master to the remote server immediately? (Since it now has the commit of those merged branches)

Comment: I recommend to update master on point D before doing the merge, then on E push it

Answer (score -1):

The short ansewr is yes.

---

There are a lot of variables that aren't pinned down in that scenario, but let's look it over:

In the simplest case, each user is doing fast-forwards when they can (without rewriting any history) and creating merge commits when they can't.  In that case, both useres started with something like

```
O <--(master)(origin/master)
```

(where any history before `O` doesn't really matter for this exercise).  User1 creates `U1` and does some work

```
O <--(master)(origin/master)
 \
  A <--(U1)
```

When they merge, this would be a possible fast-forward, so they have

```
O <--(origin/master)
 \
  A <--(U1)(master)
```

and so the push `master` and simply have

```
O - A <--(U1)(master)(origin/master)
```

User2 doesn't yet see all that, so she creates her branch, works, and fast-forward merges to get

```
O <--(origin/master)
 \
  B <--(master)(U2)
```

Now the push fails, so she could fetch and get

```
O - A <--(origin/master)
 \
  B <--(master)(U2)
```

Now if she merges (or if she had skipped the `fetch` and just `pull`ed) she ends with

```
O - A <--(origin/master)
 \   \
  \   M <--(master)
   \ /
    B <--(U2)
```

Now, notice that `origin/master` hasn't been changed; to share her work on `master`, User2 still has to push them.  IF she doesn't, then when User1 (or anyone else) makes a new branch from `master`, two things will potentially be wrong:

First, they won't see User2's work on the `master` branch.  Maybe it's owrk that would help them.  Maybe it would change how they do something.  Or maybe what they're going to do is simply going to create a code conflict with the changes they don't see.

So because of that, when they push their work, the shared `master` branch again diverges from User2's `master` branch.  After another fetch, she might see

```
O - A - C <--(origin/master)
 \   \
  \   M <--(master)
   \ /
    B <--(U2)
```

To fix that divergence, she has to at least merge `origin/master` with `master` again.  If she does only that, she gets

```
O - A - C <--(origin/master)
 \   \   \
  \   M - M2 <--(master)
   \ /
    B <--(U2)
```

If hse wants a cleaner history, she might locally rewrite history to take the original `M` out of `master` - but if `M` included any merge conflicts, she may have to redo them.

And all that wouldl still just leave her in the same state as she was in right after creating `M` - her work (from the `U2` branch) still hasn't been shared on `master` until she pushes.

---

All of that is more or less the "simplest" case.  Since you mention each user working on branches, it may be that you're using a no-ff approach to preserve branch topology; that would make all the graphs above more complicated, but the punchline is the same: until the merge of `origin/master` and `master` is pushed, the remote doesn't know about the local changes to `master`.